# Data ino pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from nsepy import get_history
import pandas as pd

def importdata(stock):
    stock_fut = get_history(symbol=stock,
           start=date.today() - timedelta(days = 3),           end=date.today(),
           futures=True,
           expiry_date=date(2022,9,29))    
   
    #print(stock_fut.columns)
    print(stock_fut[["Symbol","Number of Contracts","Change in OI","Open Interest"]])
    
a = ["ULTRACEMCO"]
    
#a = ["CONCOR", "JKCEMENT","SHREECEM","RAMCOCEM","INDIGO","ACC","BAJAJ-AUTO","ULTRACEMCO","PERSISTENT","MARUTI"]

for i in range(0,len(a)):
   #print(a[i])
   #importdata(a[i])
   df = pd.DataFrame(a[i]) 
   print(df)
```

Unable to do same with error as DataFrame is not called properly.
Also I want to join all data for all symbols in single table.

```
import requests
import json
import codecs
import pandas as pd

baseurl = "https://www.nseindia.com/"
url = f'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-oi-spurts-underlyings'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, ''like Gecko) ''Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36','accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(baseurl, headers=headers, timeout=30)
cookies = dict(request.cookies)
res = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=30, cookies=cookies)
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(codecs.decode(bytes(res.text, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8-sig'))['data'])
mini_df = df[['symbol']]
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
#print(df)
#print(mini_df)
print(mini_df.to_string(index=False))
```

Sir what if I want this symbol output to give input in below code for value of "a".

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: pd. DataFrame not giving any output when printing df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix your code with minimal modification. Hope it helps;

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from nsepy import get_history
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import codecs

baseurl = "https://www.nseindia.com/"
url = f'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-oi-spurts-underlyings'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, ''like Gecko) ''Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36','accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(baseurl, headers=headers, timeout=30)
cookies = dict(request.cookies)
res = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=30, cookies=cookies)

# hereby we use from_dict module of pandas.DataFrame in order to make a dataframe from a collection of dictionaries inside a dictionary.
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(codecs.decode(bytes(res.text, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8-sig'))['data'])

# and here we get a list unique of symbols
a = df1.symbol.unique().tolist()


def importdata(stock):
    stock_fut = get_history(symbol=stock,
           start=date.today() - timedelta(days = 3),           end=date.today(),
           futures=True,
           expiry_date=date(2022,9,29))    
   
    return stock_fut[["Symbol","Number of Contracts","Change in OI","Open Interest"]]
        
# here we add all the dataframes to a list
df_list = []
for i in a:
    temp = importdata(i)
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp)
    df_list.append(temp_df)
# and here we concatenate all of them together in a row-wise manner.    
df = pd.concat(df_list)
print (df)
```

Comment: Sir one more query for this script. How to take value of a by output of 2nd code I posted Plz. Can you update your answer with combined script plz??

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I added explanatory comments to the code.

Comment: Sir how to remove rows belonging to "FINNIFTY","NIFTY","BANKNIFTY in above DataFrame. I tried df.drop(["FINNIFTY", "NIFTY","BANKNIFTY], inplace = True) but failed. Plz suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([a[i]])
```

Comment: Can you explain plz. I tried but only symbol name there no other data output.

Comment: data is a `ndarray`.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html